# Storm: Why emitting data in loop from a Bolt hits performance?

Tags: apache-storm

I have created a Bolt that emits 100 times (for loop) 10byte message each time it called.
This causing storm act slowly.

What can cause that? full queue? memory issues?

Comment: What do you mean by acting slowly? compering to what? Is it a production environment or you local machine?

Comment: In a local machine, if I emit 100k tuples that comes directly from the spout it takes something around 1sec, but if I emit 1k tuples from the spout and then emits each tuple 100 times (using loop) from the bolt (that gets data from the spout) it takes something like 7 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase the storm internal queue buffer sizes and check the performance.

Comment: Which queue? How you suggest to change the buffer size? from storm config file or (if possible) from the config object in the code?

Answer (score 1):

```
 conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_RECEIVER_BUFFER_SIZE,             8);
 conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TRANSFER_BUFFER_SIZE,            32);
 conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_EXECUTOR_RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE, 16384);
 conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_EXECUTOR_SEND_BUFFER_SIZE,    16384);
```